# Docker Centos7+haproxy1.8 on port 80

Tags: docker

I am building a docker haproxy 1.8 custom image on top of centos 7. I want to open port 80 for the front end but whenever IO start the container, it complains about ***"cannot bind socket on port 80"***, however it can bind on 8080 and other which are not is use as usual. I believe it has to do with kernal parameters but I cannot run  sysctl in dockerfile which returns "Read-only" file system. docker run has  --sysctl commandline but it doesn't have any effect I believe.
 my Dockerfile is as follows :

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER "SAGAR"
ADD ["http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/src/haproxy-1.8.20.tar.gz", "/tmp/"]
RUN mkdir /etc/haproxy
COPY ["haproxy.cfg", "/etc/haproxy/"]
RUN yum -y update && \
yum -y install wget tar gcc pcre-static pcre-devel make perl zlib-devel openssl-devel systemd-devel make && \
groupadd -r haproxy && \
useradd -g haproxy -d /etc/haproxy -s /sbin/nologin  -c "Haproxy User" haproxy && \
chown -R haproxy:haproxy /etc/haproxy && \
chmod -R 774 /etc/haproxy && \
cd /tmp/ && \
tar -xvzf /tmp/haproxy-1.8.20.tar.gz && \
cd /tmp/haproxy-1.8.20 && \
make TARGET=linux2628 USE_PCRE=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_CRYPT_H=1 USE_LIBCRYPT=1 USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1 USE_THREAD=1 && \
make install && \
ln -s /usr/local/sbin/haproxy /usr/sbin/haproxy && \
yum clean all; 
EXPOSE 80 443 13888 9000
USER haproxy 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/haproxy", "-W", "-f", "/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]
```

My docker run command is :

```
 docker run -d --name haproxy --privileged -p 80:80 haproxy:80
```

Comment: If possible there is an application already use 80 on your host?

Comment: @atline no way. I was running this alone. and the listening ports were only  22;  error explicity says on container logs cannot bind to socket `[ALERT] 209/235335 (1) : Starting frontend http: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]
` , to tat means, its inside the container iself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `USER haproxy` before your start the haproxy, which means you are running the application with normal user.

But in linux, the normal user can just open port from 1024 ~ 65535, just root can open the port under 1024, they are called [Priviliged ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html):

> **Priviliged ports**
>
> The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them. This is a security feaure, in that if you connect to a service on one of these ports you can be fairly sure that you have the real thing, and not a fake which some hacker has put up for you.
>   The normal port number for W3 servers is port 80. This number has been assigned to WWW by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, IANA.
>
> When you run a server as a test from a non-priviliged account, you will normally test it on other ports, such as 2784, 5000, 8001 or 8080.

In fact you can see [haproxy official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy), here is its [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/blob/e52bf417dd69f7a0e37be65bbfd3ab0f1451723a/2.0/Dockerfile), they are ok to use root to start the service.

And, you may specify user if you really need it in `haproxy.cfg`, refers to [this](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#user)

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 60000
    user haproxy
```

Comment: I dont know how I missed that point. I should say thanks for the info. BTW I have haproxy user in haproxy.cfg, and everything works fine. I have other dockers working with root user as well.